# 2 openid connect in asp.net core application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid-connect

I've been trying to add second identity provider to my web app, but have a problem with the configuration.

The app has the folowing configuration

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
  options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
  options.DefaultSignInScheme = "cookie";
  options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
  options.DefaultSignOutScheme = "oidc";
})
    .AddCookie("cookie")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
      options.Authority = AppConfig.AuthorizationServerAdress;
      options.ClientId = AppConfig.OpenidApp;
      options.ClientSecret = AppConfig.OpenidAppSecret;
      options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
      options.ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.Query;
      options.UsePkce = true;
      options.SaveTokens = true;
      options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    })

    .AddCookie("cookie2")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc2", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = AppConfig.AuthorizationExternalServerAdress;
        options.ClientId = AppConfig.OpenidExternalApp;
        options.ClientSecret = AppConfig.OpenidExternalAppSecret;
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
        options.ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.Query;
        options.UsePkce = true;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    });
```

It works by default with the first oidc provider, but if I use oidc2 to log in and then navigate to my app, I'll go to my default oidc provider. It means that the second provider will be ignored.
Can somebody help me with the configuration, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both handlers will listen for the callback request from your identityprovider on URL **/signin-oidc**

So, to solve it, you need to make sure they are different, like:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
  //other options
  options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/oidc/handler1");
}
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc2", options =>
{
  //other options
  options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/oidc/handler2");
}
```

also, see [OpenIdConnect: Manually handle Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402095/openidconnect-manually-handle-callback)

But, in general I advice that your clients and apps only should trust one provider (token issuer) and let users choose how to authenticate through your primary provider, like in this picture:
[image]

Comment: The idea is right, but it doesn't help me. I added the callbackpathes and changed the client redirects urls in my providers.

Comment: What does your signing code? where you force the user to sign in? how do the user choose betweeen the two handlers?

Comment: oidc is an identity server (asp.net + oppeniddict) with default implementations. 
 oidc2 is a copy of the oidc. User opens the app and is redirected to the "oidc". The new idea is to add a secondary "oidc2" provider. The provider already exists and users use this as an internal web site. They want to use SSO from oidc2 too. The log in to the oidc2 and then go to the app. Not app -> oidc2 -> app.  just oidc2-> app

Comment: I think its  better to only support one OIDC provider for your clients and APIS, but allow users to authenticate at OIDC2 through/via OIDC1, se picture in my answer.

Comment: Ok. It was my first implementation, but I didn't find any examples for openiddict.  And my code didn't work. But Thanks. I'll try to implemen it.